# php регистрация пользователей, проверка уникальности значений

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Делаю регистрацию пользователя для своего сайта, php учу не так давно.

Данные получаю с формы -> далее проверяю их корректность, если все хорошо отправляю в БД.

Это функция у меня в отельном файле я ей передаю только значения.

```
function regUser($v1,$v2,$v3,$v4){                    
    $mysqli = @new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    if($mysqli->connect_errno)exit('Ошибка соединения с БД');

    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

    $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users`(`login`, `password`, `mail`, `date_reg`) VALUES 
    ('$v1','$v2','$v3','$v4')");

    $mysqli->close();

    return $result;
}
```

В БД поля логин и mail уникальные, и на сайте я хочу оповещать пользователя о том что если он ввел не уникальное значение, то что именно ему надо исправить логин или mail, подскажите как это можно сделать, у меня был вариант с разбитием запроса на части и потом смотреть что вернет query для каких данных.

Если у кого есть примеры из практики и код, как лучше сегодня делать регистрацию пользователей буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Неужели ни одного вопроса не возникло? :) Пишите вопросы, если будут, я дополню ответ

Comment: В данный момент действительно нет вопросов, практически разобрался. У вас отличный подробный ответ, google дальше помогает, но спасибо, если что обязательно напишу.

Comment: @Ипатьев Огромное вам спасибо еще раз, все сделал. Пример кода выложил ниже, если вам не трудно возможно вы  подскажите все или нет я сделал так как надо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы проверить существование пользователя, надо выполнить обычный SELECT запрос. Поэтому сначала научимся как выполнять SELECT запрос правильно.

Чтобы выполнить SELECT запрос с использованием переменных, надо сделать следующее:

1. Написать запрос, в котором все переменные заменить на знаки вопроса
2. Подготовить запрос к выполнению
3. Привязать переменные к запросу
4. Выполнить

В итоге получится такой код:

```
// создаем запрос SQL в котором все переменные заменены на знак вопроса
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=?";
// подготоваливаем запрос
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
// привязываем переменные к запросу
// указывая тип для каждой переменной. для простоты всегда можно использовать тип "s"
$stmt->bind_param("s", $login);
// выполняем запроc
$stmt->execute();
// получаем результат
$result = $stmt->get_result();
// из результата получаем строку
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();

// и дальше уже можем проверить, вернула БД данные или нет
if ($user) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

при таком способе у нас **никогда** не будет ошибок синтаксиса, не говоря уже об sql инъекциях.

> что такое sql инъекция? в данном случае это дыра в заборе рядом с железными воротами. Какой бы надежной авторизация не была, если переменные пишутся прямо в запрос, а не передаются отдельно, то кто угодно сможет авторизоваться под кем угодно, даже не зная пароля - просто дописав в логин кусок SQL запроса. Или даже угнать к себе **всю базу данных пользователей с логинами и паролями** целиком.

**То же самое касается и регистрации пользователя**, или выполнения запроса INSERT:

```
// создаем запрос SQL в котором все переменные заменены на знак вопроса
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `mail`, `date_reg`) VALUES(?,?,?, NOW())";
// подготоваливаем запрос
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
// привязываем переменные к запросу
// указывая тип для каждой переменной. для простоты всегда можно использовать тип "s"
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $login, $password, $mail);
// выполняем запроc
$stmt->execute();
```

Кроме того, пароль **никогда** не пишется в БД в открытом виде. Пароль надо хэшировать. Чтобы даже если у нас и угонят БД, то пароли все равно остались неизвестными.

Кроме того, соединяться с БД надо только **один** раз, и в дальнейшем везде использовать одну и ту же переменную с созданным соединением. Сначала смотрим [как правильно подключаться к mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect)

В итоге твой код может выглядеть так:

```
function checkUserExists($mysqli, $login, $email)
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login=? or email=?"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $login, $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
function regUser($mysqli, $login, $password, $email)
{
    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `mail`, `date_reg`) VALUES(?,?,?, NOW())";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $login, $password, $mail);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

И дальше же используем эти функции.

```
<?php

require 'mysqli.php';
$errors = [];
// другие проверки
// которые заполняют массив $errors
$user = checkUserExists($mysqli, $_POST['login']);
if ($user) {
    if ($user['login'] == $_POST['login']) {
        $errors[] = "логин занят";
    elseif ($user['email'] == $_POST['email']) {
        $errors[] = "email занят";
    }
} 

if (!$errors) {
    regUser($mysqli, $_POST['login'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'])
}
```

Здесь мы запрашиваем из бд пользователя, у которого либо логин, либо емейл уже есть в БД. Если пользователь находится то сравниваем значения из БД с в введенными данными и выводим сообщение. Если свопадений нет - регистрируем.

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо за помощь, пришлось еще с PDO подключением поковыряться, но сейчас все работает

Вот что получилось в итоге(в коде нет подключения к БД, оно в отдельном файле)

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php'; // Подключение к бд с помощью PDO
$regexp_valid = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9.,@а-яА-Я -]+/"; // регулярка для проверка входных данных

// Избовляюсь от нотисов в HTML, т.к. поля после неверного заполения таблицы не стираются и не надо вводить все данные заново
$result = '';
$login = '';
$mail = '';
$msg = "Поля могут содержать цифры, буквы, сивол - @"; 

// Если отправилась форма методом POST начинаем проверку данных и заносим в БД. Форма на этой же странице.
// Если заходить на страницу просто по адресу а не отправкой формы то мы на нее поподаем методом GET
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && count($_POST) > 0){        
    // Обработка данных из массива POST
    $login = strtolower(trim($_POST['login']));
    $mail = strtolower(trim($_POST['mail']));
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $today = date("Ymd");; 

        // проверка на корректность
        if(((bool)preg_match($regexp_valid, $login)) ||  $login == '' ){
            $msg = "Ошибка, логин $login - не кооректный";
        }elseif(((bool)preg_match($regexp_valid, $mail)) ||  $mail == ''){
            $msg = "Ошибка, mail $mail - не кооректный";
        }elseif(((bool)preg_match($regexp_valid, $password)) || strlen($password) < 8 ||  $password == ''){
            $msg = "Ошибка, пароль не кооректный";
        }else{
            // Проверка на идентичность с БД (что бы пользователь с одими и теми же данными не зарестрировался два раза)

            // Проверка логина
            $check_login =  $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM`users` WHERE `login`=:login ');
            $check_login->execute(['login' => $login]); // отправка подготовленого запроса вернет true если запрос сработал
            $res_check_login = $check_login->fetchColumn();// смотрим результат по колонке  если select ничего не нашел будет пусто
            // Проверка почты                
            $check_mail = $pdo->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM`users` WHERE `mail`= :email ');
            $check_mail->execute(['email' => $mail]);// отправка подготовленого запроса вернет true если запрос сработал
            $res_check_mail = $check_mail->fetchColumn();// смотрим результат по колонке  если select ничего не нашел будет пусто

            //  Проверяем что пришло из БД и если все в норме выполнится блок else где данные нового пользователся занесутся в БД
            if($res_check_login){            
                $msg = "Пользователь с таким именем уже существует";
            }elseif($res_check_mail){
                $msg = "Пользователь с таким e-mail уже существует";
            }else{
                // Выполняем insert в БД
                $reg_user= $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `users`(`login`, `password`, 
`mail`, `date_reg`) VALUES (:login,:password,:mail,:date)');
                $check_reg_yser =  $reg_user->execute(['login' => $login, 'password' 
=> $password, 'mail'=> $mail, 'date' => $today ]);

                if($check_reg_yser){
                    $msg = "Регистрация успешно завершена";
                }else{
                    $msg = "Регистрация временно недоступна, приносим извенения";
                }                   
            }  
        }
  }
?>
```

Comment: В целом неплохо, только пароль, как я писал выше, надо обязательно хэшировать. Ну и по мелочи - емейл прочерять лучше специальной функцией, пароль регуляркой проверять нельзя. Проверять только на длину и в сообщении писать про нее. Существование логина и пароля можно проверить 1 запросом. И в самом конце куча лишнего кода. Нужно только `$reg_user->execute(...); $msg = "Регистрация успешно завершена";`

Comment: @Ипатьев Понял, спасибо, исправлю. Если учесть исправление, это в целом будет боевое решение для применения на нормальном проекте?

Comment: Да, вполне. Оно уже годится, хоть сейчас в учебник. Только недочеты исправить. Я кстати зметил еще один. Надо избавиться от этой лестниц с elseif. В проверках должны быть только if без else.1 уровень. И сообщения об ошибках надо собирать в массив, чтобы вывести все разом, а не по одному. И потом проверять этот массив на пустоту. Если код вызывается не аяксом, то после вставки - редирект

Comment: @Ипатьев У меня пока главной целью было сделать сверку с базой при регистрации на уникальность некоторых значений, об остальном не думал. Замечания очень хорошие, обязательно постараюсь реализовать их все.

Comment: @Ипатьев  А почему в проверках должны быть только if без else?

Comment: потому что читать код, который без конца смещается вправо, невозможно. И потому что нет ни малейшего смысла писать здесь elseif/else.